# How to get SQLite Column Default Value to not include string quotes

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to put in default values for some columns in SQLite.  If i use single quotes to enclose the string it will include the the quotes.  The only way to not include the quotes is to use no quotes however that will not work if the string has any special characters or spaces.

An example statement I am trying to use would be of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (id INTEGER NOT NULL, [columnname] TEXT DEFAULT DefValue, PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

If DefValue is John then it works fine and the when the default value is produced in a table it does not have the enclosing quotes or brackets.
If I use 'John', "John", [John], 'John Smith' or with special characters like 'F!@#4%' the default value is produced with the enclosing quotes/brackets.  If I dont use the enclosing brackets/quotes and theres a special character as expected the query wont work.

Is there a way add a default value with spaces or special characters and wont produce the enclosing quotes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "enclosing quotes?"  SQLite (and every other SQL database with which I'm familiar) does _not_ put all string data into quotes by default.

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mre] by filling your table (by showing some lines of `insert ... `), showing a query ( `select ...`) with the described result and the output it produces. Ideally fill with several rows which provoke all variants of the problem you describe. Or maybe you need to create several tables to do so... ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query )

Comment: Consider to use line breaks in your code, just for convenience of reading.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  It was not SQLite. I will try to briefly explain.  I am using SQLite as a local database for a .NET program.  I originally did not think it was related to the .NET program because I had thought I was reproducing the issue in an SQLite editor I recently started trying out.  I realized after posting it was not reproducing in the SQLite editor.  It was late and I was tired and frustrated. 
The main issue was that in the .NET program the datadapter does not pull default values when using the dataadapter.fillschema method, so I had a subroutine pull the default values from SQLite through a SELECT query and .NET added the default values for the datacolumns.  I did not realize that it was returning the single quotes enclosing the string-literal(ie.the quotes around 'John Smith').  I had the subroutine remove the quotes before assigning the default value to the datacolumn in .NET.